# Loading XML file in Chrome using Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, google-chrome

I am working on a webpage where I am trying to load a list of items in an xml file. I have written a javascript which works fine in IE/Mozilla/Opera etc. However, for some reasons the script does not work in Chrome. I used try-catch to get the error message and it showed:

```
"A Network Error Occurred"
```

Can anyone help me with the required script? Below is the piece of code that I have been using:

```
function loadFile(){   

    try //Internet Explorer
    {
        xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDoc.async=false;
        xmlDoc.load(file);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        try //Firefox, Mozilla, Opera, etc.
        {
            xmlDoc=document.implementation.createDocument("","",null);
            xmlDoc.async=false;
            xmlDoc.load(file);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            try //Google Chrome
            {
                var xmlhttp = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.open("GET",file,false);
                xmlhttp.send(null);
                xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement;
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                error=e.message;
                alert(error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please show the content of the `file` variable. Most likely you're being blocked by chrome for cross domain file access attempt